# Is there any sort of generic dictionary where attempting to get a non-existent key will return null?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

It really annoys me that I must use `.ContainsKey` instead of just doing a `value==null` in a dictionary. Real life example:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, FooBar>();
var key = "doesnt exist";
var tmp = dictionary[key] ?? new FooBar(x, y);
```

Instead, I have these choices:

```
var key = "doesnt exist";
FooBar tmp = null;
if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
{
    tmp = dictionary[key];
} else {
    tmp = new FooBar(x, y);
}
```

Or this:

```
FooBar tmp = null;
if (!Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out tmp))
{
    tmp = new FooBar(x, y);
}
```

To me, this code is extremely verbose. Is there a built-in generic class which implements IDictionary (or otherwise allows key-value type access) but doesn't throw an exception when I try to lookup a key, and instead return null?

Comment: Why not create your own extension method?

Comment: The dictionary works like this, because there is difference between containing a null value and not containing a value at all. You would need something like two types of null. Otherwise you could not distinguish whether the value is null or the value does not exist

Comment: You could perhaps create a single-parameter `TryGetValue` extension method which behaves as you describe.  It's too bad `TryGetValue` uses an `out` parameter rather than `ref`, and can't simply leave the variable alone when the key doesn't exist, since then one could simply initialize the variable with the desired default.  If your goal was to add an item to the dictionary if it didn't already exist, you might consider `ConcurrentDictionary`, which has some interesting `GetOrAdd` methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` allows you to *store* `null` as a value, thus you wouldn't know if the key didn't exist, or just had a value of `null`.  The other problem is that `null` is only valid for `TValue` types that are reference types (or `Nullable<T>`).

Now, that said, you could write an extension method yourself to do so:

```
public static class DictionaryUtilities
{
    public static TValue SafeGet<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, TValue defaultIfNotFound = default(TValue))
    {
        TValue value;

        return dict.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? value : defaultIfNotFound;
    }
}
```

In this way, you could query your dictionary like this:

```
var sample = new Dictionary<int, string> { {1, "One"}, {2, "Two}, {3, "Three"} };

var willBeNull = sample.SafeGet(4);

var willBeHi = sample.SafeGet(4, "HI!");
```

Though, of course, the above code would return the default of value types if `TValue` was a value type (that is, if the value type was `int`, it would return `0` on not found, by default.)

Again, though, you could create two forms, one where `TValue` is constrained to `class` and one to `struct` that would allow you to return a `Nullable<T>` for value types...

Comment: `out` keyword guarantees a variable to be initialized. So the `?` operator is not required here. Just three lines: `declare x; TryGet(out x); return x;`

Comment: @abatishchev: depends, if we want a user specified default, we'd need to set it after the call, since the `out` would stomp it.

Comment: I think the better solution would be to restrict it somehow so that you could only use that extension method with nullable types

Comment: If you want to provide a default value - yes. Otherwise it will have just `default(T)`, as you mentioned in the optional parameter.

Comment: @Earlz: True, regardless the point is the OP is free to create the method in whatever flavor they like.

Answer (score 2):

For a generic collection `null` is not always a valid value and you can't write a generic method that returns `null`.  it must be default(T).

You can easily create an utility method that returns default(T) if you are sure you will not use it as *value*

Answer (score 0):

If you extend then you have to pass a default every time.
That may be what you want.
Could implement Dictionary and pass a default value in the ctor.

```
public class DictionaryWithDefault<T1,T2> : Dictionary<T1,T2>
{   
    private T2 t2Default;
    public new T2 this[T1 t1]
    {   // indexer - if the key is not present return the default
        get
        {
            T2 t2t;
            return TryGetValue(t1, out t2t) ? t2t : t2Default;
        }
        set {
            base[t1] = value;
        }
    }
    public DictionaryWithDefault(T2 _t2) { this.t2Default = _t2; }
}
```

If you want the Dictionary to not allow a value of null then you override Add.

Borrowed some syntax from JamesMH +1

Where I use something like this is a Dictionary with a composite key.

Where this suffers is if you change the default value then it changes the t2Default value.
I am working on that.
If T2 is a value type then this works.
If T2 is a reference type then would need to make a deep copy and it is not worth the hassle.